# image max-width in ul list

Tags: image, html-lists, css

`max-width:100%` is working when an image is placed inside the div, but it is not working when I add it into li.

here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cfQSL/2/)

but strange fact is, it works if I remove the style from `.pro ul` completely. Since style of the ul is defined to get the UI part done, I cant remove any of the existing style from the code.

**P.S - max-width:100% is used to stretch the image only till the extent of original size of the image. width:100% makes image to fit the device size which I do not want.**

Check this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cfQSL/9/) this is how I want it to work even in the ul list. You can resize the window to check how it works.

Comment: Whats the problem? http://jsfiddle.net/cfQSL/8/

Comment: @AbijeetPatro Problem?? max-width should be 100% not 10%. And when it is 100%, image should be scaled when you re-size the window. Currently that is not happening there

Comment: Am I assuming correct when I say that you want the image to take up the entire space of the `<li></li>`?

Comment: @AbijeetPatro: see my proposal. the image is taking full width available. and shrinks when re-sized also.

Comment: @Sowmya : your statements here and on the below answer are contradicting . What is that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: +1 I didnt know that max-width can be used something like this.. :)

Answer (score 1):

is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/uTVqM/) what you wanted?. I have made the below changes to the css.

```
.pro ul{margin:0; padding:0;  list-style:none; width:100%; white-space: nowrap; overflow:hidden;}
.pro li{  display:block; margin:0; padding:0;  }
.pro li a {display:block}
.pro ul li img{     margin:0 auto; width:100%; max-width:100%}
```

**UPDATE:**

check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kvE96/) updated fiddle. i get the exact similar output when i check on chrome & firefox. or else please specify the browser you are on.

i have just removed the `width:100%` from `.pro ul li img` style

**UPDATE 2:**

if you remove the `overflow:hidden;` property from your `.pro ul` style in your fiddle it will [work](http://jsfiddle.net/kEpu3/) as you expected. But if you have no way to edit your css, sorry.

Comment: No this is not what I want. i dont want image width to be 100% coz I dont want image to stretch beyond the original size so that I have used max-width

Comment: @Sowmya: in the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cfQSL/2/) you given. it is having original size. What exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: Deleted my answer, I hadn't seen yours. We did the exact same thing.

Comment: @mithunsatheesh Check my edited question. I want image to resize when the window is scaled.  http://jsfiddle.net/cfQSL/9/ in this demo it is working, scale the result panel to check the image resizing

Comment: @mithunsatheesh your demo is working coz you have removed width and height from the .pro ul and .pro li is changed to dispaly:block.(I haven't given width:100% in my css anywhere). As i menioned in the question I need to retain all the properties mentioned in my css.

Comment: @Sowmya: see my updated suggestion. But if you cant make any changes to the css, leave it.

Answer (score 0):

I was giving it a try and I think I got it

Check this **[fiddle](http://jsbin.com/udasiq/1/edit)**

I used positioning here..

```
 .pro ul li img{ position:absolute;}
```

If you dont want to use positioning then remove `width` and `white-space` properties from ul tag. (I dont know why, but it worked when removed)

```
 .pro ul{margin:0; padding:0;  list-style:none; overflow:hidden;  height:243px}
```

Check this **[fiddle](http://jsbin.com/udasiq/2/edit)**